# Which *.desktop files belong where?

Tags: launcher, gnome-shell, menu

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, using Gnome3 with the Frippery extensions (which, among other things, give me a bunch of "favourites" launchers in the top bar and a Gnome2-style applications menu) and I've got a lot of duplicate entries in the menu. Trying to resolve this, I find a lot of duplicate *.desktop files (which is obviously the cause of the duplicate menu entries).

However, these *.desktop files exist in several places. For example, looking at the gnome-terminal.desktop file, I find:

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers/gnome-terminal.desktop
~/.gnome/apps/gnome-terminal.desktop
~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
```

So what is what? Which desktop entries are supposed to appear where, when and why? There are a lot of desktop entries in /usr/share/applications, for example, that appear nowhere. What controls this?

None of the above bears much resemblance to the [file locations section in the FreeDesktop menu specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s02.html). Does this specification apply to Gnome3 in Ubuntu 18.04 or is there another specification?

Comment: In my installation gnome-terminal.desktop is located in /usr/share/applications only. So I assume that the multiple entries were made by you or some apps. You can check the content of the entries to determine which functionality they are offering.

Comment: @kuffy: yes, the duplications have to have been caused by something I did. The main suspec is menulibre (which I used because alacarte is rather restricted). However that's not the point: what I want to know is the difference between, say, ~/.gnome/apps/ and ~/.local/share/applications/ as a place for *.desktop files to live and if/how the location of the *.desktop files effects where they show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original location of the .desktop files is in `/usr/share/applications`. If you create your own .desktop file, or wish to modify a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, then it should go into `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: `@heynnema` OK. That's clear. Yet there are other locations on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation as well, i.e.. `~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers` and `~/.gnome/apps/` which are being used in my Gnome3 desktop environment, and the entries in `/usr/share/applications` are not user-writable. So there's more going on than just this.

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen ~/.config/gnome-panel exists because of some top panel launcher that you've installed. ~/.gnome/apps is used by some apps, like Chrome. /usr/share/applications is owned by root, so that's why it's not writable... it's to protect yourself from yourself. .desktop mods go in ~/.local/share/applications. There's nothing going on, that's just the way it works.