# How to find `.desktop` file location for a particular application

Tags: configuration, .desktop, ftp, default-programs, image-viewers

EDIT: This is not a duplicate as this question is the reverse of what the other question is asking. Here we know what is the application and we want to find its `.desktop` file that can be located in non standard places also. While the other question is about where the `.desktop` files can be placed.

---

I want to open images from an FTP server in the default image viewer rather than in the browser, so I wanted to know the path of default image viewer desktop file in Ubuntu. I tried the following:

```bsh
cd -- /usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications

$ find . -name '*.desktop' | grep image
./gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop
./gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop

$ find . -name '*.desktop' | grep view
./calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop
./calibre-lrfviewer.desktop
./evince-previewer.desktop
./shotwell-viewer.desktop
./okularApplication_ghostview.desktop
./gcr-viewer.desktop
./gnome-info-overview-panel.desktop
./org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop
./paraview.desktop
```

But I still couldn't find it. Are there any other locations where the desktop files are stored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which \*.desktop files belong where?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146307/which-desktop-files-belong-where)

Comment: @lamino This is not a duplicate as this question is the reverse of what the other question is asking. Here we know what is the application and we want to find its `.desktop` file that can be located in non standard places also. While the other question is about where the `.desktop` files can be placed. So this is one to many mapping. While the other is many to one mapping

Comment: So this is one to many mapping. While the other is many to one mapping!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A much faster and more universal search is with `locate` command:

```
$ locate '*image*desktop'
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gimagereader:gimagereader-gtk.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-disk-utility:gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-disk-utility:gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagej:imagej.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagemagick-6.q16:display-im6.q16.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagemagick:display-im6.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagevis3d:imagevis3d.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/kimagemapeditor:kde4__kimagemapeditor.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/simple-image-reducer:simple-image-reducer.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/trimage:trimage.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/screensavers/tessellimage.desktop
```

`locate` can search millions of files in a few seconds where it would take `find` many many minutes:

```
$ time find / -name '*image*.desktop'
real    0m52.563s
user    0m6.271s
sys     0m9.002s

$ time locate '*image*desktop'
real    0m0.705s
user    0m0.693s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Notice how `grep` was eliminated from original method and `find` command was ammended.

The disadvantage of `locate` is the database is updated daily. If you just installed the application you are searching for today, you will first need to run:

```
sudo updatedb
```

#### Installation

In newer versions of Ubuntu, you can install `locate` by installing the package `plocate`:

```
sudo apt install plocate
```

Answer (score 7):

##### Search `.desktop` launchers by their content

The name of the `desktop` file alone may not reveal sufficient information. The fundamental approach is to **search the content of all `.desktop` files of the system** to find the relevant one(s).

*For example*, the image viewer is displayed as `Image Viewer` in the Applications overview. Gnome Shell obtained that label from the `.desktop` file. To find the `.desktop` file (or files) that contains this string, execute

```bash
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H 'Image Viewer' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

This uses `find` to find all `.desktop` files on the system. For each of the found files, `grep` is invoked, which searches for a string in the file, in this example `Image Viewer`. The `2>/dev/null` suppresses the permission errors you inevitably get searching the root drive without root permissions.

##### Desktop launcher search order

Multiple `.desktop` launchers with the same name may exist on the system. The one that is in use depends on where it resides.

The system first searches `.desktop` files in your local `~/.local/share/applications` directory, and then searches `applications` directories that exist under the directories included in the variable `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

For example, the contents of `XDG_DATA_DIRS` can be displayed as follows

```bash
$ printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/ubuntu: /usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

The system first searches `~/.local/share/applications`, then `/usr/share/ubuntu/applications` etc. `.desktop` launchers with the same name further in this search path, or elsewhere on the system, are not used.

Answer (score 0):

Well my solution is very easy and here is how you do it if you are looking for the application with a icon in your apps

```
ls -la /usr/share/applications | grep <name_of_app_you_are_looking_for>
```

for Example i want to find location for some apps in my Ubuntu --- i want to find the desktop file for Google Chrome
[image]

But it only works for the apps inside `/usr/share/applications`