# remove Signal in ubuntu when you forgot how you installed it

Tags: uninstall, signal

[image]i don't remember how i installed Signal desktop. i think i did it with ubuntu software.
the version is v1.39.6
so i removed it with all the ways i know

- as if installed w/snap but it says here that the package does not exit

`sudo snap remove signal-desktop`

- as if installed with ubuntu software, going there and looking for it (did not find it) or using the favs or doing some console typing:

`sudo apt-get purge signal-desktop` `sudo apt remove signal-desktop`
`sudo apt remove signal-desktop`

- as if installed according to their website guidelines and as decribed in this site here [Can't remove Signal-Desktop in Ubuntu 20.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367659/cant-remove-signal-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-x)

result: nada, nothing. still there nagging me.
i can find it in this folder:

`/home/my_name/.config/Signal`

to answer a question by user535733, the folder contains: clementine, brave,chromium, blender...

i can run the app and identifying it with `ps ef`
it gives

`3543 tty2     SLl+   0:05      |           \_ /app/Signal/signal-desktop`
the app is effectively running. no error message. the only thing is that it's trying to reconnect to my account unsuccessfully.

`which signal-desktop` does not yield anything

`whereis signal-desktop` gives `signal desktop`

running `locate`yields:

`/home/user/.cache/gnome-software/odrs/io.snapcraft.signal-desktop-r4LxMVp7zWramXsJQAKdamxy6TAWlaDD.json`

`/home/user/.cache/gnome-software/screenshots/112x63/6f99df3ba355beacae962ce195d796e30327a7d05fbced571be96a443b5bed3e-signal-desktop-screenshot.png`

`/home/user/.cache/gnome-software/screenshots/752x423/6f99df3ba355beacae962ce195d796e30327a7d05fbced571be96a443b5bed3e-signal-desktop-screenshot.png`

`/home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/signal-desktop`

`/home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/signal-desktop/current`

`/home/user/.local/share/Trash/info/signal-desktop.trashinfo`

`/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.signal.Signal/x86_64/stable/a25dbb6a0dea0943848a5fe8f3e1b1b8273480bad5c597175af96297dea8abd7/files/Signal/signal-desktop`

`/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.signal.Signal/x86_64/stable /a25dbb6a0dea0943848a5fe8f3e1b1b8273480bad5c597175af96297dea8abd7/files/share/doc/signal-desktop`

`/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.signal.Signal/x86_64/stable/a25dbb6a0dea0943848a5fe8f3e1b1b8273480bad5c597175af96297dea8abd7/files/share/doc/signal-desktop/changelog.gz`

`/var/lib/snapd/sequence/signal-desktop.json`

following through i did
`flatpak list` and it yielded some files but not any signal or signal-desktop ones

still, i did `flatpak uninstall --delete-data signal-desktop` this gave an error message
but flatpak `uninstall --delete-data signal` yields

`Found installed ref ‘app/org.signal.Signal/x86_64/stable’ (system). Is this correct? [Y/n]:`

now, i'm as doubtful as a christian scientist with appendicitis.

thank you for any help.

Comment: @user535733: like i said, i think i used the ubuntu software thingy. trouble is it doesn't allow me to remove signal-desktop. just to install it.

Comment: Your output of `which` and `whereis` suggests that you have no application called `signal-desktop` installed on any of your $PATH directories anywhere on your system. Maybe it's using a different name. Maybe it's in a different directory. Or maybe it's not there at all. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: "*i see it in my favs*" does not clearly explain what you are looking at, or what your "favs" might be. Recall that we are not in the room with you. We cannot see what you are seeing. it's up to you to provide that clarity in your question.

Comment: here's all the clarity in the world, a screenshot. that shows that in my applications there is the infamous signal desktop. IT IS THERE. no sweat. the fact that `which` and `whereis` commands don't appear to give a path to the app doesn't preclude the fact that IT IS THERE.

Comment: Start by finding the location of the relevant .desktop file. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160737/how-to-find-desktop-file-location-for-a-particular-application for how to do that.

Comment: done. i hesitate to proceed because of the answer. what should i do? do i remove it? is it really the signal desktop?

Comment: Your output seems to show that you installed `signal-desktop` from a flatpak. Try using flatpak tools to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

the app was installed through flatpak

i did a search to confirm this by `flatpak search signal`

simply doing: `flatpak uninstall --delete-data org.signal.Signal`, did it

**bottom line:** when you don't know how you installed a package you run into some hassle.

just list all the possible ways it can be installed by listing the ways a package can be installed.
many thanks to user535733

Comment: THANK YOU. I also found the `/app/Signal/signal-desktop` via the pid, which was a non-existent path, and it was so baffling.